# string words with HTML tags are not outputting correctly

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am facing an issue related to wrapping the flag words with HTML. The flag words response is coming from a third-party service as an array of objects. The paragraph text is something like this:

```html
Hi, my nme is John, and I am from uas.\\nthis sentce dones mke sense.\\nHi, my nme is John, and I am from uas.
```

and the flag words response is this:

```
[
  { offset: 7, token: 'nme', type: 'UnknownToken' },
  { offset: 52, token: 'dones', type: 'UnknownToken' },
  { offset: 58, token: 'mke', type: 'UnknownToken' }
]
```

I want to wrap the flag tokens with the following HTML tag.

```html
<span class="underline">nme</span>
```

The response already has the `offset` and `token` keys, but my logic is not correctly working with these keys, I am replacing the string on the offset index, but the output is not correct.

**My logic:**

```
function replaceAt(str, index, replacement) {
  return (
    str.substring(0, index) +
    replacement +
    str.substring(index + replacement.length)
  );
}

let input = `Hi, my nme is John, and I am from uas.\\nthis sentce dones mke sense\\nHi, my nme is John, and I am from uas.`;
const flagTokens = [
  { offset: 7, token: "nme", type: "UnknownToken" },
  { offset: 52, token: "dones", type: "UnknownToken" },
  { offset: 58, token: "mke", type: "UnknownToken" },
];

flagTokens.forEach((item) => {
  input = replaceAt(
    input,
    item.offset,
    `<span class="underline">${item.token}</span>`
  );
});

console.log("Output:", input);
```

**Output:**

```
Hi, my <span class="underline">nme</span>his sentce <span <span class="underline">mke</span>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why not ``flagTokens.forEach((item) => input = input.replace(item.token, `<span class="underline">${item.token}</span>`));``? I don't think you need `replaceAt`.

Comment: Beware of the offset changing when the prior text is altered - so may want to start at the END of the text depending upon how you alter it in situ.

Comment: Show us what the desired output should look like.

Comment: You add to the string, either replace from the end to the beginning or you need to offset based on the number of characters you add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are two issues with your code.

The first one is that after you replace the first token, your string has gotten longer, and now the offsets of the rest of the tokens are wrong since they have moved forward. A solution to this is to apply the replacements from the last to the first (*since they are ordered in offset order*)

The second issue is that your replacement method `replaceAt` after inserting the replacement text it continues to add `str.substring(index + replacement.length)`. But that is wrong. You only need to add the `token` length and not the `replacement` length. So you should pass that as well in the function.

```js
function replaceAt(str, index, replacement, length) {
  return (
    str.substring(0, index) +
    replacement +
    str.substring(index + length)
  );
}

let input = `Hi, my nme is John, and I am from uas.\\nthis sentce dones mke sense.`;
const flagTokens = [
  { offset: 7, token: "nme", type: "UnknownToken" },
  { offset: 52, token: "dones", type: "UnknownToken" },
  { offset: 58, token: "mke", type: "UnknownToken" },
];

// using .reverse() here to apply the replacements
// in reverse order (from last to first)
flagTokens.reverse().forEach((item) => {
  input = replaceAt(
    input,
    item.offset,
    `<span class="underline">${item.token}</span>`, 
    item.token.length
  );
});

console.log("Output:", input);
```

Comment: Nice idea of reversing the string, I've seen this technique before but it works well in this scenario too, nice one

Comment: @NickParsons i am not reversing the string. I am reversing the list of tokens.

Comment: Sorry, yes that’s what I meant

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace()` instead

```js
const flags = [
  { offset: 7, token: 'nme', type: 'UnknownToken' },
  { offset: 52, token: 'dones', type: 'UnknownToken' },
  { offset: 58, token: 'mke', type: 'UnknownToken' }
];

// Reference the element that has the text
const p = document.querySelector("p");
// Get the element's HTML content as a htmlString;
let string = p.innerHTML;

/**
 * For each object (flag) of array flags...
 *
 * Create a regex that is a capture group (...) of the
 * current object's token value and set the (g)lobal flag
 *
 * Replace any occurrence that matches the token with itself
 * ($1) wrapped in <u>...</u>.
 */
flags.forEach(flag => {
  let rgx = new RegExp(`(${flag.token})`, "g");
  string = string.replace(rgx, "<u>$1</u>");
});

// Parse the HTML of <p> with the modified string
p.innerHTML = string;
```

```html
<p>Hi, my nme is John, and I am from uas.<br> 
this sentce dones mke sense</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The replacement solution. The error is beautifully highlighted by Gabriel.

```js
let input = `Hi, my nme is John, and I am from uas.\\nthis sentce dones mke sense\\nHi, my nme is John, and I am from uas.`;
const flagTokens = [
  { offset: 7, token: "nme", type: "UnknownToken" },
  { offset: 52, token: "dones", type: "UnknownToken" },
  { offset: 58, token: "mke", type: "UnknownToken" },
];

let output = input + "";


flagTokens.forEach(t => output = output.replace(t.token, `<span class="underline">${t.token}</span>`));

console.log("Output:", input);

document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = input;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = output;
```

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
<div>Input: <p id="input"/> </div>
<div>Result: <p id="result"/></div>
```

Comment: unsure how that would work.... what is `t` supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, have corrected it. Its the object that you are getting from the API

Comment: The `str.replace` won't update the string, it returns a new string. So since the result isn't being assigned back to `str` it won't change. It'll also not work correctly if the token to be replaced appears multiple times (as it doesn't use the index, which might not be desired, but I think `.replace()` is still a nice solution). The first solution doesn't mention that the new string with the `<span>...</span>` added to it is being fed back into the  `replaceAt()`, so the `index` is no longer correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think `.replace()` is a good and elegant solution for the general case where you want to "underline" all or just the first occurrences for a given token, but it struggles if you want to underline those at particular indexes like you have in your `flagToken` array, as you may not want to underline all or just the first occurance of a given token, but rather a particular one if they appear multiple times.

One option could be to loop through your string. If the index your on does not appear in your `flagTokens` array then you can add the current character to a resulting string (`res`). If the index does appear in your array as an `offset`, then you can add your token wrapped in your `<span>` to the resulting string `res`, and then add the length of the `token` to the current index (skipping the rest of the token) to then process the remaining indexes of the string. By keeping the original `input` string untouched, you don't need to worry about adjusting your offset based on the characters added by the `<span>...</span>`, as those are added to `res`, eg:

```js
let input = `Hi, my nme is John, and I am from uas.\\nthis sentce dones mke sense`;
const flagTokens = [
  { offset: 7, token: "nme", type: "UnknownToken" },
  { offset: 52, token: "dones", type: "UnknownToken" },
  { offset: 58, token: "mke", type: "UnknownToken" },
];

const flagMap = new Map(flagTokens.map(o => [o.offset, o]));

let res = "";
let i = 0;
while(i < input.length) {
  let item = flagMap.get(i);
  if(item) {
    res += `<span class="underline">${item.token}</span>`;
    i += item.token.length;
  } else {
    res += input[i];
    i++;
  }
}

console.log("Output:", res);
document.body.innerHTML = res;
```

```css
.underline {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to start at the end and work your way forward so you do not have to worry about the characters you are adding into the string.

```js
const input = 'Hi, my nme is John, and I am from uas.\\nthis sentce dones mke sense.\\nHi, my nme is John, and I am from uas.'

const flagTokens = [
  { offset: 7, token: 'nme', type: 'UnknownToken' },
  { offset: 52, token: 'dones', type: 'UnknownToken' },
  { offset: 58, token: 'mke', type: 'UnknownToken' }
 ];
 
 const replaceTokens = (input, tokens) => {
   const sorted = [...tokens].sort((a,b) => b.offset - a.offset);
   sorted.forEach(({offset, token, type}) => {
     const replacement = `<span class="underline">${token}</span>`;
     input = input.substring(0,offset) + replacement + input.substring(offset + token.length)
   });
   return input;
 }

const result = replaceTokens(input, flagTokens);
console.log(result);
```

Other option is keeping track what you add and adding that to the offset

```js
const input = 'Hi, my nme is John, and I am from uas.\\nthis sentce dones mke sense.\\nHi, my nme is John, and I am from uas.'

const flagTokens = [
  { offset: 7, token: 'nme', type: 'UnknownToken' },
  { offset: 52, token: 'dones', type: 'UnknownToken' },
  { offset: 58, token: 'mke', type: 'UnknownToken' }
 ];
 
 const replaceTokens = (input, tokens) => {
   let insertedOffset = 0;
   tokens.forEach(({offset, token, type}) => {
     const replacement = `<span class="underline">${token}</span>`;
     input = input.substring(0,offset + insertedOffset) + replacement + input.substring(offset + insertedOffset + token.length)
     insertedOffset += replacement.length - token.length; 

   });
   return input;
 }

const result = replaceTokens(input, flagTokens);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this solution is what you are looking for

```
function replaceAt(str, index, replacement) {
  return (
    str.substring(0, index) +
    replacement +
    str.substring(index + replacement.length)
  );
}

let input = `Hi, my nme is John, and I am from uas.\\nthis sentce dones mke sense`;
const flagTokens = [
  { offset: 7, token: "nme", type: "UnknownToken" },
  { offset: 52, token: "dones", type: "UnknownToken" },
  { offset: 58, token: "mke", type: "UnknownToken" },
];
let myTokenIndex = 1;

flagTokens.forEach((item) => {
    
  input = replaceAt(
    input,
    item.offset + (31*myTokenIndex),
    `<span class="underline">${item.token}</span>`
  );
    myTokenIndex++;
});

console.log("Output:", input);
```

Output

```
Output: Hi, my nme is John, and I am from uas.<span class="underline">nme</span><span class="underline">dones</span><span class="underline">mke</span>
```